# Hilberts tenth problem over $\mathbb R$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$

Tags: computer-science, diophantine-equations

Consider the following decision problem:

Given: An equation $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$ where $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is a polynomial with variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and coefficients in $\mathbb Z$.

To decide: Is this equation solvable in $\mathbb R$?

It is well-known that Tarski proved that this decision problem is decidable. I wonder whether this problem is decidable when we allow the coefficients to be arbitrary rational numbers.

> My question is: Is the following decision problem decidable?
>
> Given: An equation $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$ where $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is a polynomial with variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.
>
> To decide: Is this equation solvable in $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Given a polynomial $f$ with rational coefficients, we can mechanically produce a polynomial $g$ with integer coefficients such that the equation $f=0$ has a  solution in the reals if and only if the equation $g=0$ has a solution in the reals.

*Remark*: On the other hand, if we seek solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$, then whether there is an algorithm is a long-standing open problem.

Comment: Let $f$ be a polynomial with rational coefficients $\frac{p_1}{ q_1},\frac{p_2}{q_2}\dots,\frac{p_m}{q_m}$. Then $f\cdot q_1\cdot q_2\cdot\dots\cdot q_m$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ and $f\cdot q_1\cdot q_2\cdot\dots\cdot q_m = 0\iff f = 0$. Is my solution right?

Comment: @Halteproblem:  Yes, that is correct.